# how to set id to delete button when we use setvalue in Angular 6

Tags: angular

when we use setvalue then how we set the id of row to the delete button
[image]

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.education.length; i++) {   
    if ( i !== 0 ) {
      const control = <FormArray>this.editEducation.controls['educationArray'];
      control.push(this.getEducation());
    }
  this.educationArray.at(i).get('institute_name').setValue(this.education[i].institute_name); 
  this.educationArray.at(i).get('year_of_passing').setValue(this.education[i].year_of_passing); 
  this.educationArray.at(i).get('course_type').setValue(this.education[i].course_type); 
  this.educationArray.at(i).get('course_id').setValue(this.education[i].course_id);  
  this.educationArray.at(i).get('id').setValue(this.education[i].id);  
}



<button mat-mini-fab color="warn"title="Remove Fields"
    (click)="removeEducation(id)">x</button>
```

Comment: Explain better what you need and why

Comment: i am unable to set id to the delete button when we use setValue with FormArray

Comment: and plz check image

Answer (score 0):

Normally you has a formArray like

```
   <div formArrayName="educationArray">
      <div *ngFor="let item of form.get('educationArray').controls; let i = index"
             [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="id">
        <input formControlName="institute_name">
        <!---you can use item.get('username').value -->
        <button (click)="delete(item.get('username').value)">delete</button>
        <!---or you can use the "index" and your function delete get the value-->
        <button (click)="delete(i)">delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```